# How to get the values present within 4 weeks / 28 days from the existing date in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

From this table `EmpRecord`:

```
Name     |    JoiningDate      |     StartDate    
---------+---------------------+-----------------
  A           03/21/2017             05/25/2020 
  B           01/13/2020             01/29/2020
  C           04/07/2016             05/21/2020
  D           02/18/2020             02/29/2020
```

I need to fetch the result where the `StartDate` present within 4 weeks / 28 days from the `JoiningDate` where joining date should be within 1 year.

Expected results:

```
Name     |    JoiningDate      |     StartDate    
---------+---------------------+-----------------
  B           01/13/2020             01/29/2020   (16 days)
  D           02/18/2020             02/29/2020   (11 days)
```

I used this code but didn't get the expected results:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Datamining.dbo.EmpRecord
WHERE JoiningDate >= DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE())), 1, 1)
  AND Startdate <= JoiningDate DATEADD(m, -6, GETDATE()) -- this returns wrong values
```

What should be derived in the `Where` clause to achieve the desired results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [DATEDIFF()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to determine the number of days between your StartDate and JoiningDate and evaluate if that is less than or equal to 28 days.

We'll use the [ABS()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/abs-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function around DATEDIFF(). That gives us the absolute(positive) value to then evaluate against 28 days.

```
DECLARE @test TABLE
    (
        [name] CHAR(1)
      , [JoiningDate] DATE
      , [StartDate] DATE
    );

INSERT INTO @test (
                      [name]
                    , [JoiningDate]
                    , [StartDate]
                  )
VALUES ( 'A', '03/21/2017', '05/25/2020' )
     , ( 'B', '01/13/2020', '01/29/2020' )
     , ( 'C', '04/07/2016', '05/21/2020' )
     , ( 'D', '02/18/2020', '02/29/2020' )
     , ( 'E', '11/18/2020', '02/29/2020' );


SELECT *
FROM   @test
WHERE  [JoiningDate] >= DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE())), 1, 1)
       AND ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY, [StartDate], [JoiningDate])) <= 28;
```

Giving you results of:

```
name JoiningDate StartDate
---- ----------- ----------
B    2020-01-13  2020-01-29
D    2020-02-18  2020-02-29
```